# Calling Lambda event by event.get()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I came across this really good repo for my use case.
https://github.com/Serber92/loadboard.

Here, he is using

```
carrierEmail = event.get('carrierEmail', '')
```

for the most part of his code.
I am wondering how is he sending data to the lambda function.

I am aware of sending the information through 'api body' and 'api queryStringParameters'
and to access this information we use something similar to this:

```
carrierEmail = event[queryStringParameters]['carrierEmail'].
```

The question here is how is he sending the data to lambda function?

Comment: Which file are you looking at specifically?

Comment: @Marcin creatBroker.py

Comment: In your question, you mentioned `queryStringParameters`? This is for api gateway. So you want to know how to call it from api gateway?

Comment: I want to know what event is he using to call the lambda function?

Comment: @Marcin could you help me out with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873480/adding-new-attribute-to-dynamdb-table-with-updateitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event for [createBroker.py](https://github.com/Serber92/loadboard/blob/master/createBroker.py) will be of the form of (partial example):

```
{
  "email": "some-email",
  "password": "some-password",
  "websiteURL": "some-websiteURL"
}
```

In terms of API gateway, such event structure is not possible with [Lambda proxy integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format), which requires different format of the `event` object.

However, it would be possible with [Lambda custom integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html). With the custom integration you can construct `event` object passed to the lambda function of any form, including the one used in `createBroker.py`.