# Adding new attribute to DynamDB table with updateItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have table already and I want to add a new attribute to that table.
I am trying to do that with the update_item functionality of dynamDB.

use case: Bid table holds details on the bid of the product. The user accepts the bid, once the bid is accepted, have to add a few attributes to that record like the user information. Not sure if it is the right way or should I have a new table for this.

pratition key is : Pickup,
sort key is : DropOff

A Demo example that I am trying currently
currently trying to alter the same table and facing the error.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    dynamo_client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    users = dynamo_client.Table('LoadsandBids')
 
item = event['body']
print("Fuirst") 
users.update_item(
    Key={
        'Pickup': event['body']['Pickup'],
        'DropOff' : event['body']['DropOff']
                
        },
    UpdateExpression='SET #attr1 = :val1',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#attr1': 'new_field'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':val1': event['body']['new']},
    ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW'
)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

getting an error:

```
"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema",
```

Could anyone help me out of this and also suggest it I my approach is good or not?

Comment: Don't have full answer, but `role` is reserved keyword. in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.ReservedWords) they show what to do in such cases.

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: Why are you using the `ConditionExpression` at all? You're already specifying the same field as `Key`.

Comment: @Andre.IDK was referring to some doc that I found. Have made the changes

Comment: @Andre.IDK have changed the code but still getting the error:
"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema",

Comment: @sumanthshetty, can you update the question and add the Table definition? (i.e. what's the Hash key and Range key (if you have one))? So we can reproduce this.

Comment: @Andre.IDK done, 
pratition key is : Pickup,
sort key is : DropOff

Comment: @Andre.IDK solved the issue. 
the issue was with the case of the latter. Should have been "Dropoff"

Comment: Your code worked already for me btw. It was just not indented.

Comment: @Andre.IDK thank you for the help. 
the error was at my end.

Comment: @Marcin Could you help me out of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126694/dynamodb-update-operation-without-using-the-key-attribute